# Is the shortest path in flat hyperbolic space straight relative to Euclidean space?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, euler-lagrange-equation, semi-riemannian-geometry

I have the following metric
$$
ds^2 = dt^2-dx^2
$$
and I wanted to prove to myself that the shortest path for this metric is straight. I used the following relation $x=f(t)$ and
$$
S = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{1-[f'(t)]^2} \ dt
$$
If I minimize $S$, I obtain the condition $f''(t)=0$, which implies $x=ct+x_0$, being a straight line in Euclidean space. I have difficulty understanding what it means to minimize hyperbolic path distances, because the square of the distance between two points can be zero or negative. I believe my answer is not correct.

Is the shortest path in flat hyperbolic space straight relative to Euclidean space?

Comment: It's important to note that $\mathbb R^2$ with the metric $ds^2$ that you wrote down is not "hyperbolic space" -- instead, it's $2$-dimensional Minkowski space.  Hyperbolic space is a Riemannian manifold with constant negative sectional curvature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is almost correct. You have that straight lines are the critical points of the arc-lenght functional. These lines minimize arc-lenght if they are timelike or lightlike, but they maximize arc-lenght if spacelike. This is sort of expected, since the connection of this Lorentz plane is the same as the connection from $\Bbb R^2$ and the Christoffel symbols all vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to basics

That a line is the shortest path just follows from the triangle inequality.

The triangle inequality is a theorem of neutral geometry (so valid in both euclidean and hyperbolic geometry )

what else is there to say?

maybe a link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

in Euclid's elements it is proposition 20 of book 1

Comment: Note that the OP uses "hyperbolic space" to refer to the real plane equipped with the flat Lorentz (i.e., Minkowski) metric, not the usual (Riemannian, non-flat) hyperbolic plane. :)

Comment: The triangle inequality is in the other direction for timelike vectors..

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang   moved this point to a seperate question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329906/hyperbolic-geometry-and-the-triangle-inequality

Comment: @Willemien I gave an answer to your follow-up question there, I hope it helps.